# Launch Screen in angularjs

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive, angular-ui, ionic-framework

I want to create one static page in angularjs, may be like an launch screen. It should be there for three seconds and then load up my default page. How can I achieve this in angularjs or ionic? Help me out please.

Answer (score 1):

1. Create your landing page/ launch screen page
2. Inject $location to your controller
3. Set a timeout for 5 seconds, and then use $location provider to move to the next URL

   setTimeout(function(){
       $location.url('/newPageLink');
   }, 5000);

Comment: Well, you're using AngularJS, so $timeout muse be your call.. !